# Downloading a file into memory

Tags: python, temporary-files, stringio

I am writing a python script and I just need the second line of a series of very small text files.  I would like to extract this without saving the file to my harddrive as I currently do.

I have found a few threads that reference the TempFile and StringIO modules but I was unable to make much sense of them.

Currently I download all of the files and name them sequentially like 1.txt, 2.txt, etc, then go through all of them and extract the second line.  I would like to open the file grab the line then move on to finding and opening and reading the next file.

Here is what I do currently with writing it to my HDD:

```
while (count4 <= num_files):
    file_p = [directory,str(count4),'.txt']
    file_path = ''.join(file_p)        
    cand_summary = string.strip(linecache.getline(file_path, 2))
    linkFile = open('Summary.txt', 'a')
    linkFile.write(cand_summary)
    linkFile.write("\n")
    count4 = count4 + 1
    linkFile.close()
```

Comment: I would be very interested in what tutorial/book you are using to learn Python so I can recommend you a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You open and close the output file in every iteration.

Why not simply do

```
with open("Summary.txt", "w") as linkfile:
    while (count4 <= num_files):
        file_p = [directory,str(count4),'.txt']
        file_path = ''.join(file_p)        
        cand_summary = linecache.getline(file_path, 2).strip() # string module is deprecated
        linkFile.write(cand_summary)
        linkFile.write("\n")
        count4 = count4 + 1
```

Also, `linecache` is probably not the right tool here since it's optimized for reading multiple lines from the same file, not the same line from multiple files.

Instead, better do

```
with open(file_path, "r") as infile:
    dummy = infile.readline()
    cand_summary = infile.readline.strip()
```

Also, if you drop the `strip()` method, you don't have to re-add the `\n`, but who knows why you have that in there. Perhaps `.lstrip()` would be better?

Finally, what's with the manual while loop? Why not use a for loop?

Lastly, after your comment, I understand you want to put the result in a list instead of a file. OK.

All in all:

```
summary = []
for count in xrange(num_files):
    file_p = [directory,str(count),'.txt'] # or count+1, if you start at 1
    file_path = ''.join(file_p)        
    with open(file_path, "r") as infile:
        dummy = infile.readline()
        cand_summary = infile.readline().strip()
        summary.append(cand_summary)
```

Comment: I think the question is "how do I maintain the summary in memory without writing to summary.txt"

Comment: I must admit I'm not sure at all what the question is. The title is about "downloading", but there is no download at all in the code...

Comment: The downloading part is in another part of the script, but David is correct, sorry for not explaining it better. There is a site that offers a file to download, I would rather not have to download the file then open it then grab the second line, I would like to know if there is a more direct way.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the file writing with a call to `append()` on a list. For example:

```
summary = []
while (count4 <= num_files):
    file_p = [directory,str(count4),'.txt']
    file_path = ''.join(file_p)        
    cand_summary = string.strip(linecache.getline(file_path, 2))
    summary.append(cand_summary)
    count4 = count4 + 1
```

As an aside you would normally write `count += 1`. Also it looks like `count4` uses 1-based indexing. That seems pretty unusual for Python.

Comment: or use `for count4 in range(1, num_files + 1)` instead of incrementing yourself!

Comment: @agf Agreed, but I can't be 100% sure that count4 runs from 1.